# python regex not woking for multiple words (re)

Tags: python, regex, python-re

**Example**

```
import re

data = 'DisplayName                     =   Umarex Steel Storm BB-Gun   ,'
pattern = r'(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)'

re.findall(pattern, data, re.MULTILINE)
```

**Output**

Wrong result: (DisplayName, Umarex)

Right result: (DisplayName, Umarex Steel Storm BB-Gun)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*([^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tN6uD1/1).

*Details*:

- `(\w+)` -  Group 1: one or more letters, digits, connector punctuation
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?)` - Group 2: a char other than whitespace and comma, then an optional sequence of any zero or more non-comma chars and then a char other than whitespace and comma.